# Generating a dynamic table from arrays

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to generate a scrolling table with four columns, where each row is a comprised of a category from the array categoryType[], a name from the array staffName[], a number from the array contactInfo[], and an string from the array staffEmail[]. The arrays are all obviously of the same length, and the table needs to be regenerated each time because the arrays will change length if new staff members are added to the online db. I've tried generating four seperate listviews, and having them all scroll together, but that didn't work, as well as trying to create a tableview, but I couldn't get that working either, so what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: The table is regenerated each time with activity creation I assume?

Comment: @Anton Yes, it is. Data is fetched from the server on creation, and regardless of whether that changed, the table regenerates.TextView schoolOpenStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parseTest);

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose probably it's better to use ListView and Adapter.

If you need a real-time data updating, create your custom adapter extended on BaseAdapter and implement method of data retrieving from your online database. Than use your data in overridden methods implementations (getItem, GetCount, getView).

Each time when you need content refreshing, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()